# How to do a page with only rotating banner in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

i'm using Joomla as CMS. I need a component who allow me to do a page with a lot of banner, who rotates. 
Can you give me some advice ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a module for this and include it in the component area. Just use whatever banner module you would normally, assign the appropriate banners and then include it in a blank article using the loadposition plugin.

e.g.

- Create a blank article and insert the code "{loadposition mybannermodule}"
- Create a dummy menu link to the article
- Create a new banner module and configure
- Set the banner to appear in the "mybannermodule" position
- Set the module to appear for that menu item
- Publish the module

On the frontend you should see the banners appearing where your article content normally does - for that page only.